# Tensorflow Quantum Data Reuploading - Efficient SU2 Encoder circuit

Tags: tensorflow, quantum-computing, qiskit, tensorflow-quantum, cirq

The task is to classify the input vector of dim (12,) into three categories using a quantum neural network. I am following the data Re-uploading scheme to do the task which resembles to with a TensorFlow Data re-uploading tutorial, [Parametrized Quantum Circuits for Reinforcement Learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/tutorials/quantum_reinforcement_learning).
Since we have to different circuits, model and encoder circuit which is shown below.
[image]
The trainable parameters are suffixed with T and input parameters(fixed) are prefixed with I.
So, I know the input to the model input shape should be of size (12, ). But since my circuit is of 3-qubit , I need to make changes in to the call function to make it work, particularly in tf.einsum(probably). Below code shows implements reuploading pqc layer.

```
class ReUploadingPQC(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """
    Performs the transformation (s_1, ..., s_d) -> (theta_1, ..., theta_N, lmbd[1][1]s_1, ..., lmbd[1][M]s_1,
        ......., lmbd[d][1]s_d, ..., lmbd[d][M]s_d) for d=input_dim, N=theta_dim and M=n_layers.
    An activation function from tf.keras.activations, specified by `activation` ('linear' by default) is
        then applied to all lmbd[i][j]s_i.
    All angles are finally permuted to follow the alphabetical order of their symbol names, as processed
        by the ControlledPQC.   
 """
 def __init__(self, qubits, n_layers, observables, activation="linear", name="re-uploading_PQC"):
        super(ReUploadingPQC, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.n_qubits = len(qubits)
        self.observables = observables

        circuit, theta_symbols, input_symbols = generate_circuit(qubits, n_layers)
        self.circuit = circuit

        theta_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=0.0, maxval=np.pi)
        self.theta = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=theta_init(shape=(1, len(theta_symbols)), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True, name="thetas"
        )

        lmbd_init = tf.ones(shape=(self.n_qubits * self.n_layers,))
        self.lmbd = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=lmbd_init, dtype="float32", trainable=True, name="lambdas"
        )

        # Define explicit symbol order.
        symbols = [str(symb) for symb in theta_symbols + input_symbols]
        self.indices = tf.constant([symbols.index(a) for a in sorted(symbols)])

        self.activation = activation
        self.empty_circuit = tfq.convert_to_tensor([cirq.Circuit()])
        self.computation_layer = tfq.layers.ControlledPQC(self.circuit, self.observables)        

    def call(self, inputs):
        # inputs[0] = encoding data for the state.
        batch_dim = tf.gather(tf.shape(inputs[0]), 0)
        tiled_up_circuits = tf.repeat(self.empty_circuit, repeats=batch_dim)
        tiled_up_thetas = tf.tile(self.theta, multiples=[batch_dim, 1])
        tiled_up_inputs = tf.tile(inputs[0], multiples=[1, self.n_layers])
        scaled_inputs = tf.einsum("i,ji->ji", self.lmbd, tiled_up_inputs)
        squashed_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Activation(self.activation)(scaled_inputs)

        joined_vars = tf.concat([tiled_up_thetas, squashed_inputs], axis=1)
        joined_vars = tf.gather(joined_vars, self.indices, axis=1)

        return self.computation_layer([tiled_up_circuits, joined_vars])
```

The function generate_cicuit() is used to get the model show above which is also called when building the model.

```
def generate_circuit(qubits, n_layers=1):
    n_qubits = len(qubits)

    params = sympy.symbols(f'T:{n_layers*12}')
    params = np.asarray(params).reshape((n_layers, 4, n_qubits))

    inputs = sympy.symbols(f'I:{n_layers*12}')
    inputs = np.asarray(inputs).reshape((n_layers, 12))

    ckt = cirq.Circuit()
    for l in range(n_layers):
        
        ckt.append(single_rot_ry(params[l, 0, :], qubits), strategy=InsertStrategy.INLINE)
        ckt.append(single_rot_rz(params[l, 1, :], qubits), strategy=InsertStrategy.INLINE)

        ckt.append(do_entangle_cnot(qubits), strategy=InsertStrategy.INLINE)
        ckt.append(get_ckt(inputs[l, :], qubits), strategy=InsertStrategy.INLINE)
        
        ckt.append(single_rot_ry(params[l, 2, :], qubits), strategy=InsertStrategy.INLINE)
        ckt.append(single_rot_rz(params[l, 3, :], qubits), strategy=InsertStrategy.INLINE)

    

    return ckt, list(params.flat), list(inputs.flat)
```

The when I try to create model using this class with the code below, I get error.

```
def generate_model_policy(qubits, n_layers, n_actions, beta, observables):
  """Generates a Keras model for a data re-uploading PQC policy."""

  input_tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape=(12, ), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name='input')
  re_uploading_pqc = ReUploadingPQC(qubits, n_layers, observables)([input_tensor])
  process = tf.keras.Sequential([
      Alternating(n_actions),
      tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * beta),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"),
  ], name="observables-policy")
  policy = process(re_uploading_pqc)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_tensor], outputs=policy)

  return model

qubits = cirq.GridQubit.rect(1, 3)
n_layers = 1
n_actions = 3
observables = [cirq.Z(q) for q in qubits]
model = generate_model_policy(qubits, n_layers, n_actions, 1.0, observables)
```

The error is

```
Exception encountered when calling layer "re-uploading_PQC" (type ReUploadingPQC).

in user code:

File "/tmp/ipykernel_1109761/1735579080.py", line 45, in call  *
    scaled_inputs = tf.einsum("i,ji->ji", self.lmbd, tiled_up_inputs)

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 12 for '{{node re-uploading_PQC/einsum/Einsum}} = Einsum[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, equation="i,ji->ji"](re-uploading_PQC/einsum/Einsum/ReadVariableOp, re-uploading_PQC/Tile_1)' with input shapes: [3], [?,12].

Call arguments received:
• inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 12), dtype=float32)'
```

So, I need to make changes in the call function but I am not able understand what to change.